# How to cope with such sentence?

Tags: modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs, interrogatives

I wrote the following sentence and then immediately I understood that it's apperently incorrect. Now I'm not sure what is the natural way which native English speaker would say this thing.

> "**Does** anyone **could** open this file and read it?"

It is a file which we got from our college and there is a problem to open it and read it. Then I asked my classmate if it they could open it. How should I build for my case an interrogative sentence - correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most natural would probably be:

> Can anyone open this file and read it?

Alternatively:

> Could anyone open this file and read it?
>
> Is anyone able to open this file and read it?
>
> Was anyone able to open this file and read it?
>
> Has anyone been able to open this file and read it?

"Do" is an auxiliary verb, so it is followed by a bare infinitive (e.g. "she does go", "he does find"), but modal verbs (such as "could") lack infinitives and so can't be preceded by any other auxiliary - so "I will can", "I should might", "she did could" are ungrammatical.

If a declarative statement lacks an auxiliary verb, we add the dummy verb "do" before inverting the word order to form a question, i.e.

> (Declarative) I opened the file.
>
> (With dummy verb) I did open the file.
>
> (Inverted/Interrogative) Did I open the file?

If a declarative statement includes an auxiliary verb (or "be" as a main verb, or sometimes "have"), then the inversion is performed *without* adding a dummy verb, so...

> (Declarative) I am opening the file.
>
> (Inverted) Am I opening the file?
>
> (Declarative) I can open the file.
>
> (Inverted) Can I open the file?